# Does the Sensor module of codenameone work in actual devices?

Tags: codenameone

Ive struggled to get the Sensor CN1 module to work on an actual Android device and I am beginning to wonder if it at all works? Just so I don't keep banging my head against a wall. Any one gotten it to work? Ill appreciate any help.

Comment: I know people used it including Chen when he developed it. I don't know if people still use it or used it in recent versions of Android/iOS so it's possible it's completely broken at the moment. Since the code is small it's probably pretty easy to fix it.